# Question about a custom RxSwift Observable extension

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, reactivex

```
extension Observable {
    func dispatchAsyncMainScheduler() -> Observable<E> {
        return self.observeOn(backgroundScheduler).observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
    }
}
```

I found this snippet in https://github.com/artsy/eidolon

I am a `reactive` beginner here. From what I understand. `subscribeOn` applies to the whole chain whereas the `observeOn` applies operators below it.

My question is quite obvious, what exactly does this two consecutive `observeOn` do at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a typo. If you look at the definition of `backgroundScheduler` 10 lines above this operator, you will see that it's a `SerialDispatchQueueSceduler`. This means that it queues up operations and performs them in order on a background thread.

They are using it to avoid reentrancy anomalies. I'll assume that this code was written before `MainScheduler.asyncInstance` was put in the library, which does the same thing.

More info can be found in the Rx library:

> - Problem: This behavior is breaking the observable sequence grammar. `next (error | completed)?`
>     This behavior breaks the grammar because there is overlapping between sequence events.
>     Observable sequence is trying to send an event before sending of previous event has finished.
> - Interpretation: This could mean that there is some kind of unexpected cyclic dependency in your code,
>     or that the system is not behaving in the expected way.
> - Remedy: If this is the expected behavior this message can be suppressed by adding `.observeOn(MainScheduler.asyncInstance)`
>     or by enqueing sequence events in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo to me. Should be `.subscribeOn(backgroundScheduler)`